# Need clarification about cron scheduler

Tags: php, mysql, time, cron, scheduler

I need clarification about handling cron scheduler in php. I want to insert queries 'n' number of queries into a table within one minute using cron scheduler.

If time exceeds one minute without executing all queries ( ex. i have 2000 insert queries , but it executes only 500 within one minute. Remaining 1700 ), so please suggest me to handle this situation.

Note: This scheduler will execute different 'n' number of queries.

Comment: increase execution time

Comment: @hnn if i increase execution time mean it may affect next one minute records i think

Comment: then make separete crons, 1 cron holds 500 insert queries

Comment: i specified as 500 queries just for an example. Exactly we don't know how many records will executes it at a minute

Comment: Please provide more info. Where are the info to insert from? Why not using a queue or listener?

Comment: Actually when cron executes it selects number of possible records from a table and we need to store those records back into another table. The number of records may differ based on the credentials.